# File System Permissions Implementation

Tags: permissions, filesystems

We have two ways of implementing file permissions in an OS:

- Using a permission list for each file
- Using a permission list for each user

What are vantages and disadvantages of each? Which one is used in Unix?

I can think only in terms of complexity, by each file is more slow to change permissions for a set of files.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean writing "permission list". Do you mean attaching file"s access rights to the file as part of its metadatas vs setting files access rights as part of some user's database table ?

Comment: @MC68020, yes, I mean this in a architectural point of view of filesystems design.

Answer (score 1):

Since permissions need to transport *with* the data (i.e. when you unplug your USB drive and plug it back in again, the permissions need to be the same, even when your computer has no list of all the files on there), you can logically exclude one of these two options.

Also, this answers the question for disadvantages.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking from a filesystem design standpoint, I am not aware of any filesystem having ever implemented a list of users and their associated permissions on files.

[Linux supports a wide range of filesystems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#OS_support) differing on layouts, capabilities and features all either ignoring the concept of multi-users or assuming them to be split into 3 categories :  owner, group, and world vis-a-vis of each file.

In this context (of individual users agnostic file systems), implementing user private groups, one can fake some sort of per user based access rights

---

On top of this come the [Access-Control Lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access-control_list)
Most of the filesystems Linux supports can (optionally at mkfs time) offer support for them, enabling a more fine grained, per user set of permissions. Since :

- This is only an option and compatibility is to be maintained with non-ACL capable FS,
- ACL are permissions associated to some system resource and the resources filesystem manage are files (v.g. : not users)

It was rather straight forward to add extra bits to the file's metadata in the existing file system layout (vs diverging from the existing layout creating some independent list of users.